# vifm: how do I set the viewcolumn option in my vifmrc so that it applies to both panes?

Tags: vifm

I set the viewcolumn option in my vifmrc file, but when I pull up vifm only the left pane uses the option setting from my vifmrc file.  I have not been able to find out how to get it to apply to both (or all) window panes from the vifmrc.  I am trying to avoid setting it manually in the right pane and then using the set vifminfo+=tui option (which I haven't tried so I don't even know if that would work).  How do I get the viewcolumn option from my vifmrc file to automatically apply to both window panes?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prepend `windo` to your `set` command in your `vifmrc` file, like this;

```
windo set viewcolumns=-{name}..,6{size},11{perms}
```

`viewcolumns` option is [local](https://github.com/ksteen/vifm/blob/051a21a26fb6007081646402c9545adb969ad22f/data/vim/doc/vifm.txt#L1758) to window, that's why one needs to use [`windo`](https://github.com/ksteen/vifm/blob/051a21a26fb6007081646402c9545adb969ad22f/data/vim/doc/vifm.txt#L1474) prefix to apply the setting to both windows.

An example of setting `viewcolumns` for both panes should probably be added to the documentation.

P.S. This is necessary for versions up to 0.8, in future versions `set` and `filter` commands in `vifmrc` act on both windows by default.

Comment: Thanks @xaizek, this works perfectly!  I guess I expected an email to let me know that someone had answered my question and didn't realize it had been answered until now.